# not able to store in a variable selected value of listbox

Tags: vb.net, get, listbox

I am unable to get value from the selected item from the listbox.
I am trying to store a date in the variable so i can pass that to the second Query. I created the textboxtest just so I could see what was stored in the value variable and it shows only System.Data.DataRowView

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Public Sub cargarlistboxFuncionFecha()

    Dim FechaConsulta As String = "SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(Funcion_Fecha,'yy/MM/dd') AS Funcion_Fecha FROM  Funcion WHERE Pelicula_ID = " & varPeliID 'aqui va la variable que contiene el codigo de la pelicula proviniente de la pantalla de estefani
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim adapt As New SqlDataAdapter(FechaConsulta, con.cnn)
    adapt.Fill(table)

    lbFecha.DataSource = table
    lbFecha.DisplayMember = "Funcion_Fecha"
    lbFecha.SelectedIndex = 0

    Dim value As Object = lbFecha.SelectedValue.ToString
    TextBoxTest.Text = value


End Sub
Private Sub lbFecha_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbFecha.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim varfecha As String = lbFecha.SelectedValue.ToString 'alamacena Fecha
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT Funcion_Hora FROM Funcion WHERE Funcion.Pelicula_ID = " & varPeliID & " AND Funcion.Funcion_Fecha = '" & varfecha & "'"
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(Query, con.cnn)
    adp.Fill(table)


    lbHora.DataSource = table
    lbHora.DisplayMember = "Funcion_Hora"

End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to set the `.ValueMember` property so the `.SelectedValue` returns it. And if you are going to call `.ToString` method then don't declare the variable as `Object`.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but after adding lbfecha.ValueMember now it does show the date on the textboxtest but now the listbox with the dates shows System.Data.DataRowView on all its rows

Comment: `lbFecha` also needs a `.DisplayMember`. Check what this property returns. If `Funcion_Fecha` is the display and value member, then assign it to both LB properties. Also, make sure after filling the `DataTable` you have a column with name `Funcion_Fecha`. Use your debugger.